# How to check if Pending intent triggered by AlarmManager setRepeating is already running?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I would be glad to know how to check if Pending intent which is triggered by an Alarm Manager which starts an activity at a specific time given by AlarmManager.setRepeating?

**To be more specific**, I have an activity which kicks off another activity with a paticular set time, or repeating time, (which works) . But i want to know if the request was already set by the user? in that case i should not start certain values.

This is how i start the scheduled activity.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),MyScheduledReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0, myIntent, 0);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. Glad it helped. Could give a +1 which could help me. :)

Comment: Actually, you should answer your own question and accept the answer. Then this question won't show up in the "unanswered" list.

Comment: Thanks @DavidWasser I've done the same

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Ok, I think i have managed to find out how,**

```
//CHECKING IF PENDING INTENT IS ALREADY RUNNING
Intent checkIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MyScheduledReceiver.class);
alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0, checkIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
```

Thanks, hope it might be helpful for someone...

Comment: this solution doesn't work for me, the PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE make the retuned PendingIntent always null.

Comment: I know this is old, but this information is erroneous, this will check if the alarm has been set with the specified intent, not if the intent has been executed.