# Android : Get state of Alarm Manager

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm setting an alarm like this:

```
mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + PERIOD,PERIOD, pi);
```

Is there a way to get alarm manager running or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your pending intent triggered is running or not using the following code  .

```
Intent checkIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MyScheduledReceiver.class);
alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0, checkIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
```

**Useful Links:**

[How to check if Pending intent triggered by AlarmManager setRepeating is already running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793996/how-to-check-if-pending-intent-triggered-by-alarmmanager-setrepeating-is-already)

[How to check if Alarm have been set and running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214160/how-to-check-if-alarm-have-been-set-and-running)

[How to check if AlarmManager already has an alarm set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556670/how-to-check-if-alarmmamager-already-has-an-alarm-set)